# Trying to add and write data in textarea and want it to be reflected in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I am doing, I am trying to write data and at the same time want to add the data to the input field, but the jquery code I have written is not doing it, something fishy I am doing, anyone can show me a way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/4abeg2rs/

I am initially using an input field and want to disguise the user to write data in textarea because the way it is written is quite complicated if I change the input to replace textarea, my whole code server-side is breaking and I can't figure out why.

```js
$('#input_A').show();
$("#input_B").hide();
$("#input_A").focus();
$('#input_A').html($("#input1").val());
    
$("#input_A").bind("keyup paste", function() {
  $("#input_B").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="question" id="input_A" style="display:none"> </textarea>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="input_B" name="question" value="">
```

Comment: Checked it but not sure what exactly you want... here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2b98k61s/3/

Comment: Don't use `.html()` to set `<textarea>` values, use `.val()`